# Is there an unofficial API for creating Twitter applications/api keys?

Tags: php, python, twitter, twitter-oauth

I need a way to programmatically create Twitter Applications/API keys. I could make something on my own, but does anyone know of a pre-made solution?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're referring to the consumer key and consumer secret, you're not supposed to be able to create those programmatically. That's why you have to sign in to a web page with a CAPTCHA in order to create one.

Comment: Yep. Else it could lead to abuse.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but there are plenty of libraries that abstracts twitter API (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries)